# How can I pick out strings that contain two keywords from different lists?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a list of strings

```
"Measles outbreak in the U.S worse than ever"
"MMR vaccination rates in California at all time low"
"I don't live in California"
```

and two lists of keywords

```
location = ['California', 'West Coast', 'Los Angeles']
disease = ['Measles', 'MMR', 'Pertussis']
```

How can I pick out the strings that contain atleast one keyword form both `disease` and `location`.

For example, the second string should be picked out, but not the first or last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make location and disease sets, split the substrings into words and see if a word from the split string appears in both sets

```
location = {'California', 'West Coast', 'Los Angeles'}
disease = {'Measles', 'MMR', 'Pertussis'}

l = ['West Coast MMR',"Measles outbreak in the U.S worse than ever","MMR vaccination rates in California at all time low","I don't live in California"]

import re

r = re.compile("West Coast|Los Angeles|California")

for s in l:
    if r.search(s) and any(word in disease for word in s.split()):
        print(s)

for s in l:
    if r.search(s) and disease.intersection(s.split()):
        print(s)
```

`if location.intersection(spl) and disease.intersection(spl):` will only be True if at least one from the string appears in both sets.  `r.search(s)` catches the two word substrings from location.

Depending on how your actual `location` list looks a mix the set and re approach might be the fastest, checking the set first then using or `r.search(s)` where the regex is compiled to match the multi-word substrings.

You may also want to use word boundaries so you don't match `Californian` etc..:

```
 r = re.compile("West Coast|Los Angeles|\bCalifornia\b")
```

Depending on what other words can appear you may need to do other adjustments. Without knowing your actual data set then it is impossible to give a definitive or optimal answer.

Comment: This will not work if string in `strings` is `"West Coast Measles"`.

Comment: @f43d65, it will now, I missed the two  words substring originally

Comment: @Shashank,  I had a bug but it is fixed, if there are a lot of individual words then a set will be a better approach, you should time the code to see if you don't think a set approach is better, I think you may be surprised. Now the split is also only done if the first case it matched. If there are a load of individual words then re is going to be slow.

Comment: Use a raw string with re.compile to avoid errors with `'\b'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

strings = [
    "Measles outbreak in the U.S worse than ever.",
    "MMR vaccination rates in Los Angeles at all time low.",
    "I don't live in California.",
    "The West Coast has many cases of Pertussis.",
    "Do Californians even get Measles?",
]

kw_sets = [
    ["California", "West Coast", "Los Angeles"],
    ["Measles", "MMR", "Pertussis"],
]

patterns = ('|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(kw)) for kw in kw_set) 
    for kw_set in kw_sets)
compiled_patterns = [re.compile(pattern) for pattern in patterns]
filterfunc = lambda s: all(cp.search(s) for cp in compiled_patterns)
filtered_strings = list(filter(filterfunc, strings))

print(*filtered_strings, sep='\n')
```

This is a regular expression solution that targets Python 3.x.

Output:

```
MMR vaccination rates in Los Angeles at all time low.
The West Coast has many cases of Pertussis.
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, I fixed it using your idea of word boundaries.

Comment: No worries, I don't think any solution is going to be exact, there are multiple scenarios where it is debatable whether something should be match or not, the OP might enlighten us at some stage when he figures out the accepted answer won't work. I also did some tests and the sets win ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I understand sets will win when you can split stuff into individual words, however that's not guaranteed here. re.search with the alternation operator is pretty fast for finding the first of an arbitrary set of substrings within a larger string.

Comment: it will still be faster if there is a mixture where single word strings dominate

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well if I was really trying hard I would go with a [Suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) module written in C and wrapped in Python, not sets :p.

Comment: lol I had an answer half prepared using a trie but thought no that could open a whole can of worms! I spent ages yesterday on a problem trying to optimise it using trie.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't fully understand the implementation of tries and suffix trees tbh. For now, I only understand their applications and time complexities, but it's definitely on my list of things to learn. In the meantime, there are several trie implementations on PyPI, but of course, installing someone else's module is nowhere near as satisfying as importing your own.

Comment: I had a look at them all yesterday and tried a few out, some better than others, the pure python ones seem quite costly to build but are liberal in what you can store in one. Definitely a project I am going to try and do maybe using cython.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `strings` is a list containing the defined strings, then

```
location = set(['California', 'West Coast', 'Los Angeles'])
disease = set(['Measles', 'MMR', 'Pertussis'])

res = [s for s in strings if ( set(s.split()) & location and set(s.split()) & disease ) ]
print res
```

will do as needed. Note that the `set(s.split())` operation is done twice and should be factored out.

Answer (score 0):

Handling multi-word keywords correctly and more than two keyword sets nicely:

```
strings = ("Measles outbreak in the U.S worse than ever",
           "MMR vaccination rates in California at all time low",
           "I don't live in California",
           "MMR vaccination rates in California at all time",
           "low West Coast Measles")
kwsets = (['California', 'West Coast', 'Los Angeles'],
          ['Measles', 'MMR', 'Pertussis'],
          ['low', 'prices', 'today'])

for string in strings:
    if all(any(kw in string for kw in kws) for kws in kwsets):
        print(string)
```

If there were no multi-word keywords, this would also work:

```
strings = ("Measles outbreak in the U.S worse than ever",
           "MMR vaccination rates in California at all time low",
           "I don't live in California",
           "MMR vaccination rates in California at all time")
kwsets = ({'California', 'West Coast', 'Los Angeles'},
          {'Measles', 'MMR', 'Pertussis'},
          {'low', 'prices', 'today'})

for string in strings:
    if all(map(set(string.split()).intersection, kwsets)):
        print(string)
```

Comment: add `"Pertussis in California"`

Comment: Gets filtered out, like it should.

Comment: wrong string  `"MMR vaccination rates in Californian at all time"`

Comment: Gets filtered out, like it should.

Comment: remove the last set of keywords or  `"Californian MMR vaccination rates at all time low today"`

Comment: I don't have that string, so I can't remove it. But I removed the last keyword set. Now your `"MMR vaccination rates in Californian at all time"` is among the printed, like it should.

Comment: why should `Californian` be printed?

Comment: You mean the sentence containing it? Because it contains a keyword out of every keyword set. For the record: `'xkeywordx'.__contains__('keyword')`.

Comment: that is a partial match, so  `"Californian MMRfoobar vacination rates at all time prices-foo"` should be a match?

Comment: It surely can be. Depends on the interpretation. In mine it does, and I think mine is reasonable. I hope we agree that "West Coast" is either not really a "word", or not a word in "the common sense sense" (but over an alphabet including not just letters). More like a key *string*. OP also didn't say "sentences" or so but called them "strings". Also, I'd say matching "Californian" when interested in "California" is *better* than not matching it.